# Multiple rows alternative for RAND()

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am having problems with my query for selecting 100 random rows from a database with 50k of rows.

First i only used the function RAND() but that became too slow.

Now i am using this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.* FROM users AS t1 JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE picture != '' && age <= 50 && age >= 18 && username != '')) AS id) AS t2 WHERE picture != '' && age <= 50 && age >= 18 && username != '' && t1.id >= t2.id LIMIT 100");
while($q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{ echo $q['id'].'<br>'; }
```

But sometimes it gives a bunch of empty rows.

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE** I am trying this query too but it gives me an error.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FLOOR(1 + RAND() * x.m_id) 'rand_ind' FROM users (SELECT MAX(t.id) - 1 'm_id' FROM users t) x WHERE picture != '' && age <= 50 && age >= 18 && username != '' ORDER BY rand_ind LIMIT 100");
```

**mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

Comment: Getting all the rows in any order, then shuffling it in PHP (or taking a few random ones from the resulting array) might be the correct approach.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, selecting 50k rows when we actually need only 100 isn't a very good idea

Comment: @v2p: Haven't read well, my bad, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Randomise the order with RAND() and then just select limit 0,100

`order by rand() limit 0,100`

Fastest way of doing it in mysql

You may want to read this for alternatives http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/
There are some limitations to doing it the ways suggested in that article though

Answer (score 1):

If your id's in the table are sequential, why not just generate x random numbers between 0 and "max_rows".

Then do something like

`'SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE`id`in (' . implode(',', $randomNumbers) . ')';`

It will return the rows with the generated id's.

Answer (score -1):

You could use :

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT $rand,100
```

Where `$rand` is a random generated number (0-50k) from code side

Comment: Unfortunately, only the first item would be random, the rest is quasi random at best.

Comment: yes , the group of 100 rows is random not each row

Comment: anyway if the limit would be 2000,100 then not all of the next 100 users have the filters that i use in `"WHERE picture != '' && age <= 50 && age >= 18 && username != ''"`

Comment: the `LIMIT` applies AFTER the filtering NOT before