# MySQL - How to select random after select top?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

SELECT Id, Name, image, price, view FROM estore.product ORDER BY view DESC LIMIT 9

and I want select random 5 records in that query. I tried but this code  doesn't work:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Image, Price, View FROM (
    SELECT Id, Name, Image, Price, View FROM estore.product ORDER BY View DESC LIMIT 9) 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

**How can I do?** Thanks for watching?

Comment: Side-note for editing: Use `four-space indentation` for your code instead of using `this` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subquery must be named.  Try:

```
LIMIT 9) as SubQueryAlias ORDER BY RAND() 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go and read this thread
[Multiple rows alternative for RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852907/multiple-rows-alternative-for-rand/16852987#16852987)

If your table is quite large (and it probably can end up quite large being a product table) the rand() limit is quite a slow query

Comment: You can see from the query that at most 9 rows will be sorted by `rand()`

Comment: Have another look at limit clause in the subquery

Comment: Yes I see the 9 :) but it doesn't change it being slow / expensive as a query.

Comment: I just started MySQL so in this time I need my program runs and runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Image, Price, View FROM estore.product ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

(Using subquery for order and limit the same selection is madness...)